# How can I define a function type adapted to any function in golang

Tags: go

I just want to define a function type which will match all functions and I have tried this:

type funcType func(...interface{}) ...interface{}
but failed

How can I do this?

Comment: empty interfaces says nothing http://go-proverbs.github.io/ I recommend you trying to find your own concrete interface to define some common behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no function type that's compatible with any function.

The best you can do is `interface{}` to which any value is assignable to, including functions.